# How to correctly set numFmt use exceljs

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

I'm using exceljs v3.8.0, and had set numFmt for each cell as '#' for Number and '%' for Percent. It works fine for LibreOffice , but for MS Office the format is being set as CustomFormat, insted of Number/Percent. How can I set the format correctly? Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you figure out a way to set it correctly?